# Как использовать php–скрипты в расширениях хрома?

Tags: php, chrome-extension

Как использовать php–скрипты в расширениях хрома?

Answer (score 3):

В хроме не предусмотрено PHP движка. PHP изначально, как язык, предназначен для динамической генерации веб-страниц со стороны сервера. Для расширений хрома используется JavaScript, c помощью него осуществляется доступ к [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples/) браузера.

Но если Вы хотите по каким-либо причинам целенаправленно использовать именно PHP, можете написать (или найти уже готовую библиотеку) интерпретатор в JavaScript. В Chrome Web Store уже есть несколько расширений для работы с PHP - можете установить, распаковать и посмотреть как оно работает для примера.